# What kind of Java syntax is "== null? false:true;"

Tags: java

I am looking through code and wondering what this means:

```
Boolean foo = request.getParameter("foo") == null? false:true;
```

It's gotta be something that converts the returning String from getParameter() into a Boolean.

But I've never seen this kind of Java with a questionmark and colon (except in a foreach loop).
Any hel appreciated!

Comment: sometimes I hate statements like this without proper brackets. should be more readable like this: `Boolean foo = (request.getParameter("foo") == null) ? false: true;`

Comment: Be aware that if the request parameter is foo=false then the foo variable will be set to `true`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's the ternary operator. The snippet:

```
Boolean foo = request.getParameter("foo") == null? false:true;
```

is equivalent to:

```
Boolean foo;
if (request.getParameter("foo") == null)
    foo = false;
else
    foo = true;
```

or (optimised):

```
Boolean foo = request.getParameter("foo") != null;
```

The basic form of the operator is along the lines of:

```
(condition) ? (value if condition true) : (value if condition false)
```

Answer (score 19):

That's the ternary operator:

```
(condition) ? if-true : if-false
```

The whole thing could've been written as:

```
Boolean foo = request.getParameter("foo") != null;
```

Which IMO is cleaner code.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that in this case it's used unnecessarily.

Comment: +1 for pointing out this. Generally is not the best to use the ternary operator to return a boolean value.

Answer (score 1):

The `?:` is an `if` you can have *inside* an expression.

The Java Tutorial describes it here: http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

(go to ConditionalDemo2)

Answer (score 0):

It is shorthand for

```
Boolean foo;
if(request.getParameter("foo")==null)
{
 foo = false;
}
else { foo = true; }
```

Comment: And longhand for the most sensible way to write it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The whole thing could be just

```
Boolean foo = (request.getParameter("foo") != null);
```